# Calling Scalar Function on a linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to call a scalar function on a linked server but I am having a little trouble setting it up. I am hoping to set it up as a function on my server.
Below is the best I came up with.

I am trying to wrap an openquery statement within the function on my server. However, the query works by itself by I am not able to return the results without causing an error.

```
USE POWERVIEW
GO
ALTER FUNCTION DBO.FN_VAR_DUMPNAME (@DUMPLOC NVARCHAR(40))  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @DUMPLOC NVARCHAR(40)='D11'
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(800)
    DECLARE @param Nvarchar(20)= @DUMPLOC
    DECLARE @retval NVARCHAR(40)   

    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)=N'@retvalOUT NVARCHAR(40) OUTPUT'
    DECLARE @innersql nvarchar(400)

    SET @innersql = 'SELECT POWERVIEW.DBO.FN_VAR_DUMPNAME('''+''''+@param +''''+''')'
    SET @sql = 'select * from openquery(MINESQLSERVER,'''+ @innersql +''' )' 

    ***RETURN EXEC sp_executesql @sql --This line does not work***
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

SQL Server does not allow functions to call dynamic SQL.  Hence you cannot do what you want.

You have other problems as well:

- `return exec` is not something I've every seen before.
- `exec` returns an integer.
- The function returns a string.

You will need to solve your problem using some other method -- a stored procedure comes to mind.